# Instantiating and Using a Method of a Class Within a Function

Tags: python, function, class, parameters, instantiation

I'm trying to instantiate a class within a function, then call a method within the class inside the same function, like this:

```
# Define the class
class myclass:
    def __init__(self,string_to_print):
         self.string_to_print = string_to_print

    def myclass_func(self):
         print(self.string_to_print)


# Define the function that utilizes the class
def func(class,func,str)
    instance = class(str)
    class = class.func()


# Run the function that utilizes the class
func(myclass,myclass_func,str)
```

But I am getting an error like "'myclass' object is not callable". Why is this? Additionally, I expect my 'class = class.func()' line is wrong; if it is, what is the correct way to call the method from the recently instantiated class?

Edit: fixed mistake in class declaration

Comment: You define classes with `class myclass:`, not `def myclass(self):`

Comment: Whoops, sloppy mistake there - I'm paraphrasing the issue that's in my actual code to simplify, so that issue isn't in the actual code.

Comment: Please show the actual code, we can't answer a question about something we can't see.

Comment: You can't use a variable `func` in `class.func`. That should be `getattr(class, func)(str)`. Anf `func` needs to be a string that names the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use method names as global variables. If you want to call a method dynamically, pass its name as a string and use the `getattr()` function.

```
# Define the class
class myclass:
    def __init__(self,string_to_print):
         self.string_to_print = string_to_print

    def myclass_func(self):
         print(self.string_to_print)


# Define the function that utilizes the class
def func(class,func,str)
    instance = class(str)
    return getattr(instance, func)()


# Run the function that utilizes the class
func(myclass,'myclass_func',str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your class using the *class* keyword rather than *def*.

Create an instance of the class.

Define a function that will try to execute the function given by its name.

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self,string_to_print):
         self.string_to_print = string_to_print

    def myclass_func(self):
         print(self.string_to_print)


myclass_instance = myclass('Hello world')

def execute_function(instance, function):
    getattr(instance, function)()

execute_function(myclass_instance, 'myclass_func')
```

**Output:**

```
Hello world
```